# Mahout CVB topics file

Tags: java, mahout

I can't understand the output, maybe someone can help

cvb command

```
bin/mahout cvb \
-i /work/matrix \
-o /work/cvb -k 10 -ow -x 20 \
-dict /work/sparseVectors/dictionary.file-* \
-dt /work/topics \
-mt /work/models
```

After cvb and vector dump

```
bin/mahout vectordump -i /work/topics \
-d /work/sparseVectors/dictionary.file-* \
-o /work/cvb-topic \
-dt sequencefile --vectorSize 10 \
-sort /work/topics \
-p TRUE
```

the file cvb-topic has something like

```
0   {0:0.5380152557598438,09:0.4619846630645179,10:1.541304295897372E-8,08:1.5405183424669223E-8,04:1.4964621316424798E-8,01:1.0302427985842305E-8,00:7.566567734425231E-9,1:7.394593812516846E-9,1.180:6.745071922943742E-9,07:3.3841292288528656E-9}
```

What do i do with it next ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, to get probabilities for words, use instead `-i /work/cvb`